# JXTreeTable and BorderHighlighter Drawing Border on All Rows

Tags: java, swingx, jxtreetable

I'm using a BorderHighlighter on my JXTreeTable to put a border above each of the table cells on non-leaf rows to give a more clear visual separator for users.

The problem is that when I expand the hierarchical column, all cells in the hierarchical column, for all rows, include the Border from the Highlighter.  The other columns are displaying just fine.

My BorderHighlighter is defined like this:

```
Highlighter topHighlighter = new BorderHighlighter(new HighlightPredicate() {
    @Override
    public boolean isHighlighted(Component component, ComponentAdapter adapter) {
        TreePath path = treeTable.getPathForRow(adapter.row);
        TreeTableModel model = treeTable.getTreeTableModel();
        Boolean isParent = !model.isLeaf(path.getLastPathComponent());
        return isParent;
    }
}, BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(2, 0, 0, 0, Color.RED));
```

I'm using SwingX 1.6.5.

When it's collapsed the top BorderHighlighter shows correctly:
[image]

When it's expanded, the non-Hierarchical columns show the BorderHighlighter right, but not the Hierarchical column:
[image]